# Pull request showing changed files that are not actually changed

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request, git-diff

I am tasked to do **code reviews** on PR from multiple devs.

I face an issue where:

1. Developer "One" Remove one line and make a PR

2. Developer "Two" Remove the same line and make a PR
3. Developer "Two" s PR got merged into master before Developer "One"
4. In Developer "One" PR, the Changed file on Github is still listed.

I reproduced this issue in a minimal repo https://github.com/tolotrasam/git-merge-diff-test/pull/1/files and as you can see on this link, it says they are comparing `master` branch
with  `dev-one`'s branch and it shows that there is a change done.
However, in reality the two branch are exactly the same.

[image]
This confuses me as code reviewer as I just want to focus on the actual changes.
What should I tell developer to do with his branch to hide all changes that has been already done by other developers ?

Comment: A good practice would be to regularly do a `git pull` on master/feature-branch so that you work on a up-to-date branch history.

Comment: I totally agree but in this case that is not possible because both developers did the same change at the same time before any of them got merged